# Is it possible for a human to be cryonically preserved in vacuum?

Tags: cryogenics

So, let’s say a guy, we’ll call him Jeff, has been chosen by the mighty god user98816 to be transported into the future. Unfortunately, user98816s godly time-machine is busted, so he decides to just freeze Jeff for a couple hundred years.

But, alas! cryonic preservation doesn’t exist in the era that Jeff is unknowingly about to leave! So, god/user98816 decides to have old Jeffy preserved by accident. Jeff is promptly dumped in the vacuum of space, in constant orbit around the moon at just the right speed so that he remains permanently in darkness. He freezes, naturally, but in the future the magic of nanotech will make it be possible to thaw out Jeff without damaging his tissues, which is the main problem faced by cryonic doctors (cryonicists?) today.

So, the thawing and revival process having been dealt with, the only problem is the initial freezing. What conditions are needed for a person to endure being frozen in this way?

Comment: What research have you done? Its the freezing that causes damage. ice tends to form long cell piercing spikes, which is the main problem faced by cryogenics today.

Comment: I don't think there is a spot where you could orbit the moon while staying in its shadow.   Perhaps just drop Jeff in a permanently shadowed crater instead?

Comment: @GaultDrakkor tie a knot in his willy so he can't pee and hope the urea builds up in his blood and tissues rather than his bladder just bursting, get him stupidly drunk and keep him that way while you feed him nothing but pickled arctic cod for a month (their antifreeze is mostly urea and we already covered that but it can't hurt) .. you want high blood and tissue content of alcohol and urea for their antifreeze properties, might also help if blood viscosity is a bit higher too, so [ponders] salted pickled arctic cod with added Trans fats, saturated fats, and lots and lots of sugar?

Comment: ^ Almost certainly won't work but its gotta be worth  try ;) he's gonna wake up with the mother of all hangovers if he survives the freezing, defrosting and resuscitation though.

Comment: Vacuum is not cold, it's nothing.  This is why vacuums can keep stuff hot as well as cold.  He can lose heat by radiation, which is certainly too slow to keep him from rotting from the bacteria in his body.

Comment: In addition to Willik's answer, the body will not freeze fast enough to prevent damage to the brain and other tissues as a result of hypoxia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The body will dessicate.**

In vacuum, tissue fluids will boil.  This will facilitate cooling.  If some fluids freeze before they boil they will proceed to rapidly sublimate away into the vacuum.

Salt crystals will compete with vanishing ice crystals as regards which will disrupt cell membranes more.

There will be no coming back.

Comment: This is the correct answer, which is simply, "no."